# Argument is missing error while creating one to many relation in Prisma Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am using prisma/postgresql and creating one to many relation but while creating comment I get "Argument "user" is missing" error. while other models are working when relation created in same way.

I am getting user's id from cookie which was stored as JWT token when I verify this token I get user's id, I am using this id to reference the user.

Here are my models -

```
model User {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  username String 
  email String
  password String
  comments Comment[] 
  questions Question[] 
  answers Answer[] 
  reputation Int @default(0)
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
}

model Question {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String 
  title String
  bodyText String
  comments Comment[] 
  answers Answer[]
  upvote String[] @default([])
  downvote String[] @default([])
  acceptedAnswer String @default("")
  views Int @default(0)
  tags String[] @default([])
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
  
}


model Answer{
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  user User  @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String 
  question Question @relation(fields: [questionId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  questionId String 
  bodyText String
  comments Comment[] 
  upvote String[] @default([])
  downvote String[] @default([])
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
}


model Comment {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  question Question? @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "question")
  postId String
  answer Answer? @relation(fields: [answerId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, map: "answer" )
  answerId String
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade) 
  userId String
  commentText String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updated DateTime @updatedAt @default(now())
}
```

Here is route

```
app.use("/questions/:id/comment", (commentPost function is called here));
```

Here is my code I am using nodejs with express -

```
async commentPost(req, res) {
    try {
      const { commentText } = req.body;

      // This is question's id
      const { id } = req.params;
      

      const cookies = req.cookies["auth_token"];

      // verifyToken is id of the user
      const verifyToken =
        cookies && jwt.verify(cookies, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      if (verifyToken) {
        console.log("this is user id while creating comment", verifyToken);
        const comment = await prisma.comment.create({
          data: {
            commentText,
            userId: verifyToken,
            postId: id,
          },
        });
        res.status(201).send(comment);
      } else {
        res.status(404).send("User not found");
      }
      res.send("ok");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("got error in comment controller commentPost", error);
    }
  }
```